# Interactive time series data over categorical feature

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly, bokeh

I am new to python. I want to learn how make an interactive plot, this is a time series data that I want to show DATE over categorical column (CODE) by selecting Source and ID and also once for all data per ID.
I also want to show the Code as a label over the bar, if this is bar plot or over a dot if this is dot plot.

I know how to make a simple graph but I dont know how to develop further.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt      
ax = df.groupby(['DATE', 'CODE']).size().unstack().plot.bar()
ax
```

```
     ID     DATE        CODE                SOURCE
0   P04  2016-08-08      f                  m1
1   P04  2015-05-08      f                  m1
2   P04  2010-07-20      v                  m3
3   P04  2013-12-06      g                  m4
4   P08  2018-03-01      h                  m4
```

Another Try :

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

p = sns.countplot(data=df, x='DATE', hue='CODE')
p.legend(title='CODE', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')

for c in p.containers:
    # set the bar label
    p.bar_label(c, fmt='%.0f', label_type='edge')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot timeseries data against categorical column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75593113/plot-timeseries-data-against-categorical-column)

Comment: No It doesnt because it not interactive, I want it to be interactive to choose the code and see the result on each code..etc