# Plot timeseries data against categorical column

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I plotted a huge dataset with x axis as date and y axis a categorical variable.
I tried with the code as follows but the plot is unreadable.

I want to show it in specific date, specific event (Code) happened based on different sources such as creating a timeline with lines, dates, and text.

```
     ID     DATE        CODE                SOURCE
0   P04  2016-08-08      f                  m1
1   P04  2015-05-08      f                  m1
2   P04  2010-07-20      v                  m3
3   P04  2013-12-06      g                  m4
4   P08  2018-03-01      h                  m4


x2 = df.groupby(['DATE', 'CODE']).size()
x2.plot.bar()
```

[image]

Expected output (creating a timeline with lines, dates, and text which is here is code
) :

[image]

My another try with the code provided by r-beginners :
[image]

Comment: What the expected output will looks like. Draw a simple sketch in order to fix ideas.

Comment: Thanks I updated the question with expected plot

Comment: Like showing all event on a timeline and line and annotated lines as codes

Answer (score 1):

The sample data in your question does not lead to the expected output. The expected output seems to be the [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib)[timeline](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/timeline.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-timeline-py), so I would quote that data and create a graph in [plolty](/questions/tagged/plolty). The graph object you will use is a graph object.

- First, you draw a bar chart of the Level data.
- Second, you draw a horizontal line at position 0 on the y-axis.
- Third, you add a marker in scatterplot marker mode.
- Fourth, you annotate the version number in scatterplot text mode.
- Fifth, you add the version number in scatterplot text mode.
  The reason for this much loop processing is to set the annotation position up or down depending on the value.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.graph_objects as go

names = ['v2.2.4', 'v3.0.3', 'v3.0.2', 'v3.0.1', 'v3.0.0', 'v2.2.3',
          'v2.2.2', 'v2.2.1', 'v2.2.0', 'v2.1.2', 'v2.1.1', 'v2.1.0',
          'v2.0.2', 'v2.0.1', 'v2.0.0', 'v1.5.3', 'v1.5.2', 'v1.5.1',
          'v1.5.0', 'v1.4.3', 'v1.4.2', 'v1.4.1', 'v1.4.0']

dates = ['2019-02-26', '2019-02-26', '2018-11-10', '2018-11-10',
          '2018-09-18', '2018-08-10', '2018-03-17', '2018-03-16',
          '2018-03-06', '2018-01-18', '2017-12-10', '2017-10-07',
          '2017-05-10', '2017-05-02', '2017-01-17', '2016-09-09',
          '2016-07-03', '2016-01-10', '2015-10-29', '2015-02-16',
          '2014-10-26', '2014-10-18', '2014-08-26']

# Choose some nice levels
levels = np.tile([-5, 5, -3, 3, -1, 1],int(np.ceil(len(dates)/6)))[:len(dates)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names,'Date': dates, 'Level': levels})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=df['Date'],
    y=df['Level'],
    showlegend=False,
    width=0.05,
    marker=dict(
        color="red"
    )))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['Date'],
    y=[0]*len(df),
    showlegend=False,
    line_width=2,
    line_color='black'
    ))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['Date'],
    y=[0]*len(df),
    mode='markers',
    line_color='black',
    showlegend=False,
    marker=dict(
        color="white",
        size=8,
        line=dict(
            color='black',
            width=2)
    )))

for row in df.itertuples():
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=[row.Date],
        y=[row.Level],
        mode="markers+text",
        marker=dict(color='red'),
        showlegend=False,
        text=[row.Name],
        textposition='bottom center' if row.Level <=0 else 'top center',
            ))

fig.update_xaxes(type='category', tickvals=df.index, ticktext=[x.strftime('%Y-%m') for x in df['Date'].dt.date],tickangle=-45)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[df['Level'].min()-2, df['Level'].max()+2,], visible=False, showgrid=False, showticklabels=False)
fig.update_layout(height=400, title="Version history", template=None)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot but what if I have too many date that more than 2 (each date) and the line overlap and the text are would just be on top of each other what is the best way to avoid this?

Comment: I added the plot that is provided by your code. it is so messy because of huge data. Do you have any idea? or do you think another plot could be better for it ?

Comment: If you look at the output created using my code, the first thing you will see is that the annotation string is too long, which makes it ugly. As a way to address this, you might consider adding a column of abbreviated names. Also, the crowded bar chart needs to be addressed by dividing the graph by category.

Comment: Thanks, how can I make it interactive? like choosing one year and it shows me all that happened in year 2016 ?  I also sorted the data frame based on date but I see still it doesn't take into account the sorted date.  and I also change the column of bars based on different CODE (in my dataframe)

Comment: Do you expect a specifically similar experience to the interactive you commented on? That and this timeline graph tends to have a lot of modifications depending on the data. Would you be willing to add about 20 rows of publicly available and real data to the question?

Comment: Unfortunately the data is restricted and I can not provide even a single row but the sample is added. Thanks

Comment: If you can't publish it, I don't blame you. I'm sorry I can't help you solve your issue. My response was able to show that Plotly can draw a graph equivalent to the timeline in matplotlib. I wish you luck in resolving the few remaining issues.

Comment: I think this is the point of sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Plotly is a good source for interactive charts.  It's a little difficult to tell exactly what you want, but this should give you some ideas.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['P04', 'P04', 'P04', 'P04', 'P08'],
 'DATE': ['2016-08-08 00:00:00',
  '2015-05-08 00:00:00',
  '2010-07-20 00:00:00',
  '2013-12-06 00:00:00',
  '2018-03-01 00:00:00'],
 'CODE': ['f', 'f', 'v', 'g', 'h'],
 'SOURCE': ['m1', 'm1', 'm3', 'm4', 'm4']})
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

fig = px.scatter(df, x='DATE', y='CODE', color='SOURCE')
fig.update_traces(marker={'size': 15})
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I want to show each event on a line like Creating a timeline with lines, dates, and text

Comment: Then you're going to need to provide more information in your question.